# Invalid Argument in IE7/8 Google Maps API V3

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been stuck with this error message for a couple of days and I wish I would get some comments or assistance.
Here is the error message :

> SCRIPT87: Invalid argument. 
>   ViewportInfoService.GetViewportInfo?1m6&1m2&1d77.283613&2d-109.22812899999997&2m2&1d77.283614&2d-109.22812799999997&2u2&4sen-US&5e0&6sm%40184000000&7b0&8e0&9b0&callback=*xdc*._g999fe&token=82683, line 1 character 18

On javascript debugging in IE7/8 document mode, I am able to see the eval code error location in file :

> SCRIPT87: Invalid argument.  eval code (5), line 9 character 180

And the following section of eval5.js file highlighted:

> function br(a,b){2==Z[tc]?a.nodeValue=b

This is triggered only when the page does an AJAX postback to refresh the map and not when I load the map initially in IE7/8 doc mode. *Also I dont get any errors while I am running the page on FF or Chrome or even in IE9.*

I have put the Java script generated on AJAX call on JSFiddle for additional insights. (http://jsfiddle.net/SVwr7/).

I have investigated the code js code generated and commented and checked for errors, but I have not been able to zero on the erroneous section.
As based on other "Invalid Argument in IE-7/8 related to google maps", I have checked for :

1) trailing commas
2) any syntax errors etc.

Thanks.